# CORS issue with WSO2 API Manger 1.8.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API manager 1.8.0.I am getting CORS issue while trying to call my secured API.I referred this link https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Invoke+an+API+using+Swagger and configured my server with CORS parameters .But still i have CORS blocking issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Chrome extension allow-control-allow-origin or else you can get rid of the CORS issue by using this line of code.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

This will sort out the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header issue.